# Why has the behavior of my tab key changed on mac

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, voiceover

I'm on a mac m1 big sur, yesterday when I was testing with voiceover on a webpage I would

start voiceover
get message I was on webcontent to go into webcontent press VO-Shift-down arrow
do that
then I could press the tab key and tab to the first button in webcontent

I have as far as I know done nothing to change behavior.
Now when I press the tab after getting into web content it selects a button on the browser - it does this in both FF and Safari.

the same thing happens really without voiceover but it is there it is a real problem for me because I need to test keyboard navigation as well.

Even if I focus on something in the page - like opening a dropdown and I hit the tab key it only tabs through the chrome. I need to tab into the page!

Please help it is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only toggle I'm aware of for that is in System prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts
'Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls'

[image]

You can toggle this with  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>    <kbd>Fn</kbd>   <kbd>F7</kbd>  or  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>    <kbd>F7</kbd>  depending on which way you have your F-Keys set, or you can disable or change that in Keyboard prefs > Shortcuts > Keyboard

[image]

Comment: thanks, so I guess like I said somehow I turned this off with some keyboard combo / trackpad gesture. if only there was a way to require you to use the system preferences tool to actually change a system preference.

Comment: There is - added to answer.